# How to use multicore in this case?

Tags: parallelization

Say I have something like this:

```
myfun[dataA,X1,Y1,Z1,W1];
myfun[dataB,X2,Y2,Z2];
myfun[dataC,X3,Y3,Z3];
(* with many more of the same *)
```

Each would take about 5 to 10 minuets to run. The function takes many arguments, some have default values.

With lots of these functions, I am currently dividing them into 4 different notebooks, then run them on different kernels, so that I am using 4 cores fully. But I think there is a better way to do this?

I want to know how to group them and run them at the same time?
Say with 16 different calls to `myfun`, can I ask Mathematica, to use all 4 cores?
If one core finishes a single run, then move on to the next run? So there are always 4 cores running?

Thanks!

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes, I have been reading them. But I see a lot of them uses a "Table" as an example? But in my case, most of the arguments to `myfun` are different. Do I have to setup a table in some way?

Comment: You could also `ParallelMap` or `ParallelSubmit` your jobs. I would suggest you try some of the documentation examples to get an idea. As for the number of cores, parallelization works on kernels. Where each kernel will run is a different story (which works out fine usually,though). Try `AbsoluteTiming[ParallelMap[Pause, {1, 1, 1,1}]]` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's straightforward for simple cases! Just as @Yves Klett commented:

```
f[a_, b_: 1] := (Pause[.3]; a + b)

(* List of arguments to be passed for each job *)
jobs = {{0}, {1}, {0, 3}, {2, 2}}

Map[f @@ # &, jobs] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.205, {1,2,3,4}} *)

ParallelMap[f @@ # &, jobs] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.309, {1,2,3,4}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Aisamu's solution is clean, and is what I'd recommend for a bigger project or if you do this a lot.  But for a quick and dirty solution, the following works well:

```
Parallelize[{expr1, expr2, expr4, ...}]
```

`expr1`, `expr2`, etc. will be evaluated on separate kernels.

Demonstration:

```
Parallelize[{$KernelID, $KernelID, $KernelID}]
(* {4, 3, 2} *)
```